# How do I nest a for loop to print a multidimensional Array?

Tags: java, arrays, nested

Within my program, I have created an Array that has now been converted from an int to an multidimensional Array of Strings `employeeNamesA[2][i]` i now want to use a String builder so that i can print this all in one JOptionPane.showMessageDialog. I am having issues trying to get my nested loop to work.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder (employeeNamesA.length);
    for (int i=0; i<employeeNamesA.length; builder.append(employeeNamesA[][i++]))
        {
        for(int j=0; j<2; builder.append(employeeNamesA[j++][]))
        builder.append("\n");
        }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employees with new Salary: " + builder.toString() + "PBI will now be paying this much more in total salary: $" + (totalSalary - totalNewSalary));
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `employeeNamesA` is supposed to be first and last name like `[["Bob", "Jones"],["Steve", "Miller"],...]` in which case you'd really want it to be `employeeNamesA[i][2]`

Comment: Also, if you know that the length of one half of your array is fixed, is there really a need for a nested loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder (employeeNamesA.length);
    for (int i=0; i<employeeNamesA.length; i++))
        {
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
            builder.append(employeeNamesA[i][j]+"\n");
        }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employees with new Salary: " + builder.toString() + "PBI will now be paying this much more in total salary: $" + (totalSalary - totalNewSalary));
```